# Is "e.g." ever needed in parenthetical citations?

Tags: citations, writing-style

It seems to me that "e.g." is rarely needed in parenthetical citations because readers assume that the works listed are examples taken from all works on the topic. For example:

"This theory has been disproved by numerous researchers (e.g., Jones, 2012; Kelvin, 2022; Stone et al., 2019)."

Why would "e.g." be needed in that citation? "Numerous" already hints that there are too many works to list them all and thus the three works given are examples.

Is there any authoritative source that addresses the use of "e.g." in parenthetical citations?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "e.g.". I use it intentionally whenever I'm citing an intentionally selected subset of the relevant papers. I have never been told by an editor or style guide to get rid of it.

Comment: Some people may take 3 to be "numerous". Adding e.g. makes it clear that it's more than 3.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're right that it isn't a requirement. It's an option you can use. In general, I think the "e.g." is used more for clarity in "citation signaling". Its presence clearly signals that there are more examples, whereas its absence is silent on this point. The choice of sources can provide another level of signaling. If they are review articles or textbooks, the reader might get a different idea of the size of the literature on the topic than if the sources are primary research works, etc. So think about what you want to signal with a given citation, and phrase it accordingly. Parenthetically, I seem to remember an answer on this site mentioning using "e.g." in some citations to discourage reviewers from suggesting additional papers to cite...

> "This theory has been disproved by numerous researchers (e.g., Jones, 2012; Kelvin, 2022; Stone et al., 2019)."
>
> Why would "e.g." be needed in that citation? "Numerous" already hints that there are too many works to list them all and **thus the three works given are examples**.

(Emphasis mine.) That's not necessarily true. Without the "e.g." or "for example", the cited works could be, e.g., review articles cataloging the literature or listing the "numerous researchers" claimed to exist.  If you don't mind that being a possible interpretation, leaving out the "e.g." is fine. (I suppose they could be review articles even with the "e.g.", but in that case I would prefer "see, e.g.,".)

Also, consider the citation without the mention of "numerous researchers", i.e. "This theory has been disproved (e.g., Jones, 2012; Kelvin, 2022; Stone et al., 2019)." vs "This theory has been disproved (Jones, 2012; Kelvin, 2022; Stone et al., 2019).". The former implies there are more sources disproving the theory, but the latter could be interpreted in several ways. Is the list of sources exhaustive, is it just a selection, or is it perhaps some authoritative treatments of the literature?

Comment: Following your logic, it seems that a large number of citations would need "e.g.", since authors don't usually read or cite all works on a topic. In fact they can't even realistically be aware of all works. Wouldn't this then lead to overuse of "e.g."? That is the problem I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: @Eggy I expanded the answer somewhat. In my opinion, the "e.g." is an optional signaling tool. Like with other devices, I would encourage judicious use.

Comment: I find that the overuse of "e.g." is characteristic of specific authors, more like an individual habit. (I am a faculty editor.) In my experience, the norm is to not use "e.g." I wish I could find an authoritative source on this to direct authors to.

Comment: @Eggy I write like this, and it's a habit I invented myself, via a first-principles justification similar to the one described in this answer. If an authoritative source said not to, I would just do it anyway. If your intention is to discourage authors who do this habitually, I doubt you'll have much luck.

Comment: My intention is to find a credible source that states the accepted scholarly standard for using or not using "e.g." in parenthetical citations.

Comment: Another alternative to consider could be adding "etc." at the end if you like the style better. Of course, whether that is appropriate will depend on the specific scenario.

Comment: @Eggy: I think the reason you’re not finding such a source is because there *isn’t* a fixed standard for this.  I fully agree with you that some authors overuse it, and that that’s bad style, and when giving advice/reviews I might well suggest removing it sometimes — but that’s just like how some authors overuse “In summary…”, “Indeed…”, “…the abovementioned…”, and many other words or phrases.   As this answer explains, there are some circumstances where it’s quite appropriate, and the upvotes and comments show reasonable consensus support for that.

Comment: I've accepted Anyon's answer and upvoted PLL's response as well. For a definitive answer, I contacted the editorial expert for the APA manual. She essentially confirmed what Anyon and PLL state, that "e.g." is sometimes appropriate and helpful and there are no rules about this. I will continue to weed out "e.g." where it serves no purpose.  In answer to Michael Mior, there is no academic style that allows "etc." at the end of a parenthetical citation. Thanks to all who contributed thoughts on this!

Comment: @Eggy I have looked around a little bit to see if I can find any resources weighing in on the topic, but I've basically only found an APAStyle tweet confirming it's an option. There are also detailed guidelines specific to legal writing, but that field is rife with idiosyncrasies, so I don't think they generalize.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, Anyon.